# Firstname-lastname swapping in BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I am writing a paper for an Elsevier journal -- Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews -- where the bibliography style for authors' names should be like this: `lastname firstinitial`

```
[1] Singaravel RMM, Arul SD. Studies on battery storage requirement of PV fed
wind-driven induction generators. Energy Conversion and Management
2013;67:34--43.               
[2] Rydh CJ, Sandén BA. Energy analysis of batteries in photovoltaic systems. Part
II: energy return factors and overall battery efficiencies. Energy Conversion
and Management 2005;46:1980–2000
```

However, I am using the `elsarticle-num.bst` style provided by Elsevier. My reference style currently looks like this: `firstinitial. lastname`

```
   [1] G. Pepermans, J. Driesen, D. Haeseldonckx, R. Belmans, W. Dhaeseleer,
Distributed generation: definition, benefits and issues, Energy Policy
33 (6) (2005) 787--798. doi:http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.
enpol.2003.10.004.
URL http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/
S0301421503003069

   [2] R. Yan, S. Roediger, T. K. Saha, Impact of photovoltaic power
fluctuations by moving clouds on network voltage: A case study of an
urban network, in: AUPEC 2011, 2011, pp. 1–-6.

   [3] C. Limsakul, R. Songprakorp, A. Sangswang, P. Parinya, Impact of
photovoltaic grid-connected power fluctuation on system frequency
deviation in contiguous power systems, in: IECON 2015 - 41st Annual
Conference of the IEEE Industrial Electronics Society, 2015, pp.
003236–003241. doi:10.1109/IECON.2015.7392599.
```

I want to have a reference style following the lastname-firstinitial setup.

Also how to get rid of URL and doi fields without deleting them from `.bib` file?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `elsarticle-num.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file, and name the copied file (say) `elsarticle-num-mod.bst`. Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly -- edit only a copy.
- Open the file `elsarticle-num-mod.bst` in a text editor. The program you edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file, locate the function `format.names`. (In my copy of this file, the function starts at line 495.)
- In this function, locate the following line:

  ```
        "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$
  ```

  Change this line to

  ```
        "{vv~}{ll}{ f{}}{ jj}" format.name$
  ```

  You can probably guess that `vv`, `ll`, and `jj` denote the "von", "lastname", and "junior" components of a name. With the change in place, the abbreviated firstname(s), without terminating "dot", will be placed after rather than before the lastname component.
- Next, locate the function `write.url`; it should start at around line 485. The function definition should look like this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {write.url}
  { url empty$
      { skip$ }
      { "\newline\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * write$ newline$ }
    if$
  }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
  FUNCTION {write.url}
  {}
  ```

  If you were to think that the modified function does nothing at all, you would be correct. :-)
- Finally, locate the function `format.doi` (ca. line 1080). It should look this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.doi}
  { doi empty$
      { "" }
      { doiprefix doi * doiurl doi * make.href }
    if$
  }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.doi}
  { "" }
  ```
- Save the file `elsarticle-num-mod.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}` to `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-mod}`, and perform a full recompile cycle: latex-bibtex-latex-latex to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abcd, 
   author = "Anna Brenda Carla Duthor and Walter Xavier Yves Zwicki",
   title  = "Thoughts",
   year   = 3001,
   url    = "http://someurl.com",
   doi    = "1.2.3.4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-mod}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```